# Google Drive isRoot attribute of Parent returns Nil

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

I'm retrieving the files that match a given query in my drive account using a wrapper that I created

```
files = get_files_by_query session, "title = 'Competitors' and trashed = false"
```

This returns an Array of Google::APIClient::Schema::Drive::V2::File objects

From the rails console I'm able to retrieve the parents of the first file in the array.

```
files.first.parents.first.id
```

However, when I attempt to retrieve the isRoot

```
files.first.parents.first.isRoot
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: Expected boolean, got NilClass.
```

Which is very strange because when I inspect the contents of the parent, the hash is displayed and isRoot is clearly false or true, but never nil.

Not sure if this is related, but right after the error. If I reattempt the first command

```
files = get_files_by_query session, "title = 'Competitors' and trashed = false"
```

The results are returned as an Array of Hash objects and not Google::APIClient::Schema::Drive::V2::File objects.

Below are the wrappers used above.

```
def get_files_by_query session, query
  get_files session, {'q' => query}
end

def get_files session, parameters
  drive = session.discovered_api("drive", "v2")
  result = session.execute(api_method: drive.files.list, parameters: parameters)
  if result.status == 200
    files = result.data.items
  else
    puts "An error occurred: #{result.data['error']['message']}"
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've worked around this by making another api call and retrieving the parent. Then I check if the parent objects has an array of size 0 for it's parents. If so then it is in the root folder.

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in the schema parsing in the ruby client which is triggered as soon as the parents collection is accessed. The first entry is getting converted correctly, but all subsequent entries and requests break. Looking in to it and hope to have a fix soon.

Comment: FYI - Confirmed it is a bug in the autoparse gem which is used to generate the classes. Should have new gems out in a day or so. In the mean time, if you'd like to try the fix, clone https://github.com/sqrrrl/autoparse/ and build/install the gem locally.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't wait so I found a workaround as described above, but I'm glad it is fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of an FYI since this was addressed in the comments, but the issued that caused this has been fixed in the client library for a while now.